# Center Elements in HStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I am trying to implement a text field that is centered, but I cannot seem to do so.  I tried doing it in 3 different ways, but it is still leading aligned.

```
//Mobile Number Field
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        
                        //Enter your number field
                        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 6){
                            Text("+ \(loginData.getCountryCode()) \(loginData.phoneNumber)")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(Font.custom("URWDIN-Thin", size: 20))
                                .padding(.top, 40)
                                .frame(alignment: .center)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        
                    }
```

So I tried aligning it to center via the HStack and VStack constructors, and also the frame of the text.  My result is still this:
[image]

With the user inputted text being leading aligned as well.  Any insight as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HStack` aligns *vertically* in the center. `VStack` aligns in the center, but you added it inside an `HStack` and then pushed your stack to the left with the `Spacer()`.

Just add a `Spacer()` before the `VStack`. Or just the following:

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    Text("In the center")
    Spacer()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to implement a text field you should use TextField…  but I suppose than you want to align a Text instead so, implement this:
 `.multilineTextAlignment(.center)` on your code.

If you want to explicitly center your Text change your padding parameter with this: `.padding(.horizontal, 40)`.

```
//Mobile Number Field
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        
                        //Enter your number field
                        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 6){
                            Text("+ \(loginData.getCountryCode()) \(loginData.phoneNumber)")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(Font.custom("URWDIN-Thin", size: 20))
                                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        
                    }
```